# button handler not getting called in jquery/jasmine

Tags: jquery, jasmine

My code is working fine on browser but not when I use Jasmine. This fails my unit test set up.

I have a form with a button.

```
<div class="templates">
            <div  class="problem-view">
                <h3 class="title"></h3>
                <p  data-name="description"></p>
                <pre><code data-name="code"></code></pre>
                <form>
                    <textarea class='u-full-width answer'></textarea>
                    <div>
                        <button class='button-primary check-btn'>Check Answer</button>
                        <p class='result'></p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>  
        </div>      
       </div>
```

I have set handler for the button in app.js inside a function

```
learnjs.problemView = function(data) {
    var view = $('.templates .problem-view').clone();
    function checkAnswerClick(){
        console.log('checking answer');
        if(checkAnswer()){
            console.log('setting to correct');
            resultFlash.text('Correct!');           
        }else{
            console.log('setting to incorrect');
            resultFlash.text('Incorrect!');
        }
        return false;
    }
    console.log('inside pv')
    var b = view.find('.check-btn');
    b.click(checkAnswerClick);  
}
```

From Jasmine, I am calling its click method but it is not getting working. I do not see console print `console.log('checking answer');` I see error in browser `Expected '' to equal 'Correct!'`. This is because the `<p>` should be set to either `Correct` or `Incorrect` but it is empty!

```
describe ('answer section',function() {
    it('can check correct answer by hitting a button', function(){
        var v1 = view1.find('.answer').val('true');
        console.log('clicking');
        var b1 = view1.find('.check-btn');
        var b2=$("#b")
        console.log("events: b:"+b2.html()+","+$._data($("#b"),"events"));
        b1.click();
        console.log('v1 is '+v1.val());
        console.log('b1 is '+b1.html());
        var r =view1.find('.result');
        console.log('r is '+r.text());
        spyOn(learnjs,'checkAnswerClick');
        expect(view1.find('.result').text()).toEqual('Correct!');
        expect(learnjs.problemView.checkAnswerClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Added more explanation

on browser, the files which will be used are public/index.html and public/app.js. For Jasmine, I have a helper function, SpecHelper.js which copies content of public/index.html into public/test/index.html because jasmine uses public/test/index.html I think (still learning this stuff)

SpecHelper.js

```
var fixture;
var view1;

function loadFixture(path) {  
  var html;
  var test;
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/index.html',
    success: function(result) {
      html = result;
    },
    async: false
  });          
  return $.parseHTML(html);
}

function resetFixture() {
  if (!fixture) {
    var index = $('<div>').append(loadFixture('/index.html'));
    var markup = index.find('div.markup');
    console.log("markup :"+markup.html())
    fixture = $('<div class="fixture" style="display: none">').append(markup);
    console.log("fixture is "+fixture.html());
    $('body').append(fixture.clone(true, true));
  } else {
    //console.log("3. fixture is "+fixture);
    $('.fixture').replaceWith(fixture.clone(true, true));
  }

}

beforeEach(function () {
  resetFixture();
  view1 = $('.templates .problem-view').clone(true, true);
  console.log("view1:"+view1.html());
});
```

public/test/index.html looks likes this. Basically, the body of this index.html gets changed by call to resetFixture in beforeEach (defined above) in SpecHelper.js

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.3.4</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.css">

  <!-- App Dependencies -->
  <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- Test libraries -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/boot.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="SpecHelper.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app_spec.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So before running each spec, the contents from public/index.html should get copied to public/test/index.html and from there, a new view should get created. The specs are defined in app_spec.js which is used by Jasmine to run the test cases. One of the test cases is described above

I am guessing that the view1 should get cloned from fixture along with event handlers (because I am now using clone (true, true). This view1 is available in app_spec.js and b1.click should work. Note that `expect(learnjs.problemView.checkAnswerClick).toHaveBeenCalled();` also fails indicating that the click's callback is not getting called.

Errors in browser:

1. Expected '' to equal 'Correct!'.
2. Expected a spy, but got undefined.    <-- maybe I am using Spy incorrectly

This is the new `describe` which solved the problem. See the comments below.

```
describe('problem view', function() {
        var view1;  
        beforeEach(function () {
            view1 = learnjs.problemView('1'); //this is where I am registering the click event callback. I had to call this. I wasn't doing so earlier
        });

        describe ('answer section',function() {

            it('can check correct answer by hitting a button', function(){
                console.log("in It - view1:"+view1.html())
                var v1 = view1.find('.answer').val('true');
                console.log('clicking');
                var b1 = view1.find('.check-btn');
                var b2=$("#b")
                console.log("events: b:"+b2.html()+","+$._data($("#b"),"events"));
                //b1.click(learnjs.problemView.checkAnswerClick);
                b1.click();
                console.log('v1 is '+v1.val());
                console.log('b1 is '+b1.html());
                console.log("2nd events: "+$._data($("#b"),'events'));
                var r =view1.find('.result');
                console.log('r is '+r.text());
                //spyOn(learnjs,'learnjs.problemView.checkAnswerClick');
                expect(view1.find('.result').text()).toEqual('Correct!');
                //expect(learnjs.problemView.checkAnswerClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to change your HTML code

`<button class='button-primary check-btn'>Check Answer</button>`

into

`<button class='button-primary check-btn' type='button'>Check Answer</button>`

Because `<button></button>` in a `<form></form>` will auto set `type='submit'` if you don't set `type='button'`.And it will auto submit this form and refresh your page by default.

Maybe this is the reason why you can't see 'checking answer' in console.

---

I tried this code in my local enviroment

```
<body>
  <div class="templates">
    <div  class="problem-view">
        <h3 class="title"></h3>
        <p  data-name="description"></p>
        <pre><code data-name="code"></code></pre>
        <form>
            <textarea class='u-full-width answer'></textarea>
            <div>
                <button class='button-primary check-btn' type="button">Check Answer</button>
                <p class='result'></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  
</div>      

      <script>
var view = $('.templates .problem-view').clone();

problemView = function(data) {
    function checkAnswerClick(){
        console.log('checking answer');
        if(checkAnswer()){
            console.log('setting to correct');
            resultFlash.text('Correct!');           
        }else{
            console.log('setting to incorrect');
            resultFlash.text('Incorrect!');
        }
        return false;
    }

    var b = view.find('.check-btn');
    console.log(b)
    b.click(checkAnswerClick);  
}

problemView();

describe ('answer section',function() {
        it('can check correct answer by hitting a button', function(){
            var v = view.find('.answer').val('true');
            console.log('clicking');
            var b = view.find('.check-btn').click();
            console.log('v is '+v.html());
            console.log('b is '+b.html());
            var r =view.find('.result');
            console.log('r is '+r.text());
            expect(view.find('.result').text()).toEqual('Correct!');
        });
})
</script>
</body>
```

Although this code throw a error `checkAnswer is not defined`, but I can see `checking answer` in my console.
I think the reason that you even can't trigger the click event is that the variable `view` that you declare in function `problemView` is not the same as you use in function `describe`.

---

I think the problem is

```
var $dom1 = $('.templates .problem-view').clone(true, true);
var $dom2 = $('.templates .problem-view').clone(true, true);
```

`$dom1` and `$dom2` are totally two different objects.

I can't understand why you bind event on the cloned Dom instead of binding event directly on the original Dom like this:

```
learnjs.problemView = function(data) {
    var view = $('.templates .problem-view');// remove .clone()
    function checkAnswerClick(){
        console.log('checking answer');
        if(checkAnswer()){
            console.log('setting to correct');
            resultFlash.text('Correct!');           
        }else{
            console.log('setting to incorrect');
            resultFlash.text('Incorrect!');
        }
        return false;
    }
    console.log('inside pv')
    var b = view.find('.check-btn');
    b.click(checkAnswerClick);  
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Anyhow, I have set form submission to false in checkAnswerClick. The issue seems to be that checkAnswerClick is not getting called when `b.click();` is executed. I even changed all clone APIs to clone(true,true) so that all events are also copied but that is not working either. Surprisingly, the code works without Jasmine

Comment: @Manu Chadha can you show more detail about your code ?I am not sure the `var view = $('.templates .problem-view').clone();` which you defined in `learnjs.problemView` is the same as in `var b = view.find('.check-btn').click();`I tried on my local and move the 'var view = $('.templates .problem-view').clone();' outside the function then it seems work

Comment: added more code. I changed `view` to `view1` to avoid confusion. I also added a spy. I have verified that `view` is not in scope of app_spec.js.

Comment: Is there a way to find if the button has any events attached to it. I have tried `$._data` but the result comes as undefined. I do not know if I am not using it correctly or whether the actually there are no events attached to the button

Comment: I tried this - Instead of calling b1.clickI(), I changed it to `b1.click(function(){    console.log("dummy");}); b1.click();`. I got the print `dummy` if I use the previous code but if I remove the second `b1.click()` then I dont get `dummy` print. It seems that in my original code, when I call `b1.click()` it is being treated as registering the callback instead of executing the click event!

Comment: I still think the problem is the way you use `view` and `view1`.In function `problemView ` you cloned a dom `$('.templates .problem-view')` and save it in `view`, then you find the button on this dom and bind click event on it.But in `jasmine` function `beforeEach` you cloned another dom `$('.templates .problem-view')` and save it in `view1`.The dom saved between`view` and `view1` is totally diffrent.So although you bind event on `view` dosen't means you bind event on `view1`.

Comment: Then you can see what in `jasmine` function `describe` .`var b1 = view1.find('.check-btn')` what you have now in b1 is the button in the dom which you cloned and saved in variable `view1`.But this is not the same dom which you cloned and saved in variable `view`.So that the button `b1` has never bind any click event.

Comment: I got this working. There was a problem in the way I was loading the view. In summary, you are correct that view1 was different from view. Basically the place where I was registering the call back (learnjs.problemView) wasn't getting called at all in Jasmine because of the way I had written the test case. Thanks for your help and sorry that the mistake was due to something totally different.